# proving a group

Tags: abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

Consider the group ($[0; 2\pi)$;$\oplus_{2\pi}$) where $\oplus_{2\pi}$ means addition modulo $2\pi$. Define
$S_1$ as the following subset of $\mathbb{C}$

$S_1$ = {$z \in \mathbb{C}; z = e^{i\theta}; \theta \in ([0,2\pi);\oplus_{2\pi})$} ;
together with the usual multiplication of complex numbers. Show that this is a
group.

I started the problem by substituting  $z = e^{i\theta}$ = $cos\theta + isin\theta$. To prove it is a group I decided to try and draw a cayley table. However im not sure how to start calculating this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be way easier to use the periodicity of $\;\sin x\,,\,\,\cos x\;$ ?!

Comment: I think that keeping the exponential form is an advantage here

Comment: I am unsure how to use $+_{2\pi}$ when the group doesn't include $2\pi$

Comment: Can't you directly use $e^{i\theta_1} e^{i\theta_2}=e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)\pmod{2\pi}}$

Comment: fyi,  if you've reached isomorphisms yet,  what's going on here in effect is that you're showing the isomorphism between the group of rotations of a circle and addition of real numbers mod $2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It is easy to show that $e^{i\theta_1}\cdot e^{i\theta_2}=e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)\pmod{2\pi}}$ **(Since,** $e^{2i\pi}=1$ **)**. This would show that the group operation of $S_2$ is binary.

If $e^{i\theta}$ is identity, then   $e^{i\theta_1}\cdot e^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta_1}=e^{i(\theta_1+\theta)\pmod{2\pi}}$, can you find what $\theta$ is? Similarly, you can find an expression for inverse **(using properties of modulus)**

$(\mathbb{C}^*,.)$ is associative and hence any subset of it too.

Comment: For the inverse property am I correct to say: $e^{i\theta}$ inverse is $e^{-i\theta}$. So $(e^{i\theta}.e^{-i\theta})mod2\pi =1$

Comment: But is $e^{-i\theta}$ in $S_1$? note by definition of $S_1$, $e^{i\theta}\in S_1$ if $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Does that condition fail and therefore it is not a group?

Comment: No. It is a group. We have to be a little tactful here. How does $e^{2\pi-\theta}$ sound for an inverse?

Comment: Sorry this is still confusing me. Does it now become $e^{2\pi -\theta}$ $e^{i\theta}$ . So $e^{2\pi-\theta+i\theta}$

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot the $i$ in the power.

Comment: okay so it become $e^{2i\pi}$=1